# Getting time series data when each day is a table (Google Analytics, Big Query)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics

I have some Google Analytics data in Big Query where the datasets are different websites and the tables are sessions from a given day.

So take this query as an example:

```
SELECT sum(totals.pageviews) as Pub1
  FROM `ga_data.1010101010.ga_sessions_20220711`
```

In this example:

1. ga_data is my project
2. 1010101010 is my dataset (a single publication)
3. and ga_sessions_20220711 is the table for July, 11 sessions

So that query gives me the total page views for the day. What I'm wondering is two things:

1. How do I extend this query across all of the tables for all days to get daily totals?
2. How do I extend this query across all of the datasets for all daily totals on all websites?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

See answers below:

*1. How do I extend this query across all of the tables for all days to get daily totals?*

You can query multiple tables using a [wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables):

```sql
SELECT sum(totals.pageviews) as Pub1
  FROM `ga_data.1010101010.ga_sessions_202207*`;
```

Output:

[image]

*2. How do I extend this query across all of the datasets for all daily totals on all websites?*

You can set the dataset in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` as an array, then loop through the array using `IF` and [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate)

```sql
DECLARE schemas ARRAY<string>;
DECLARE query string;
DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE arrSize INT64;

SET schemas = ARRAY(select schema_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA);
SET arrSize = ARRAY_LENGTH(schemas);

LOOP

  IF i < arrSize THEN 
    SET query = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM `<your-project>.",schemas[OFFSET(i)],".*`");
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
    SET i = i + 1;
  END IF;

END LOOP;
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I think it should be `ga_data.1010101010.*` instead of `.ga_sessions_202207*` otherwise it will exclude all the tables which are not for July. And also  if there is any other dataset in the project that also needs to be filtered out in  `select schema_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`